# Backbone relational fetching a model that already exists

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I would like to know if there is a way to override an existing relational model after a fetch.

Example:
I have a method on an API that returns a random model. So I created a new instance of the model client side and performed a fetch:

```
var x = new MyModel();
x.url = 'random';
x.fetch();

// If it exists it will throw "Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate more than one Backbone.RelationalModel with the same id per type! "
```

This example works fine unless I have already have an instance of that model client side. Is there a way for me to determine if that model already exists client side after a fetch and update that model instead?

Answer (score 0):

backbone-relational has a built in method for this in 'findModel' which returns the model if found:

[backbone-relational docs](http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-findModel)

You should be able to add a conditional statement to catch

```
if( x = MyModel.findModel({id: id}) ) {}
else {
  x = new myModel();
}
```